# getting files off ftp connection

Tags: java, c++, python, sockets

I have been given  a project where i need to write a program which runs on a server. This program needs to open an ftp connection to another server and pick up a file and place it in a given folder.

I dont know where to start although i think i need some sort of socket prgramming... can anyone help me with where to start ? what language or wat ? C++ of java is prefered...

I dont need a GUI just somethign executable
so shell scripting or command line or even a desktop application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- With Java, I would start from [Apache Commons FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).
- With Python, I would start form [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html).
- With C++, you may find the answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244095/c-ftp-library).

Answer (score 2):

If Java is available, ftp4j may be a good choice.

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/

Comment: I prefer this if you are using Java. ftp4j support make ftp connection via http proxy, while Apache Commons does not.

Answer (score 1):

This should help for Java: [Apache commons net](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

Answer (score 0):

You need explain more about in order to get a clear answer

What kind of application you want to run on your server (web application, desktop application-- command-line or with graphical user-interface)?

Although I dont know whether it fits your problem, I would recommended Qt framework for C++ which have a nice class QFTP, checkout it example

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/network-qftp.html

notice that Qt is a heavy weight framework

Comment: dont need a GUI but need it to executable so any doesnt matter

Answer (score 0):

Is fetching the file the only thing that the program does? If so, I wouldn't write a program at all, but use an existing one instead. Try `wget` or `curl`.